# How do I know when Data finished downloading

Tags: swift3, completionhandler

I would like to know when the function below has finished downloading the data.

I know I can use a completion handler, but this is in an NSObject and I'd like to know when to return the completion handler for this function, making sure the video is downloaded completely and ready to go, before the function returns the completion handler, and my View Controller resumes it's logic.

Thanks :)

```
func downloadVideo(identity:JSON_Video){
    // use guard to make sure you have a valid url
    let videoId = identity.video_id!
    let videoString:String = "\(Constants.endPoint_video)\(videoId).mp4"

    guard let videoURL = URL(string: videoString) else { return }
    let library_url = self.findVideo(video: identity)

    if self.findVideo(video: identity) != nil{
        print("Video exists. No need to download")
        print("Existing video \(library_url!)")
    }else{
        print("Video not found. Downloading now")

        // Variables to input on request
        let loginString = Constants.loginString
        let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

        // URL request
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: videoURL)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        urlRequest.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        // set up the session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        // make the request
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            // do stuff with response, data & error here
            if let error = error{
                print("Data Session Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print(response ?? "No response")
                return
            }
            if let data = data {
                print("Incoming video....")
                print("Data: \(data.description)")

                if let finalDatabaseURL = self.videosBaseUrl()?.appendingPathComponent("\(identity.video_id!).mp4"){
                    print("Copying from: \(videoURL)")
                    print("Copying to: \(finalDatabaseURL)")

                    do {
                        try
                        data.write(to: finalDatabaseURL)
                        print("Writing data to file")
                        // *****
                        // How do I know when data finished writing?
                        // Completion handler goes here ?
                        // *****
                    }catch{
                        print("Error writing data to file")
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }

           }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: "Writing data to file" it is actually "file successfully written"

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus. It looks like it's true. I thought data.write(to url) was when the file starts being written but it is indeed when it's done writing.